# adding wrapping tags to text before AND after a specific tag with jquery

Tags: jquery, dom

I am trying to create a details and summary tag structure on repeating blocks of html that include paragraphs and break tags.

My divs have a specific class and I want to use jquery to find content with. Specifically the first break tag of each paragraph assigned to my css class would be used as a marker, with everything before the first break being wrapped by `<summary></summary>` tags and everything within the entire matching paragraph to be inner wrapped with a  tag pair.

So to give an example of the html before and after.  Before the change it would look like this...

```
<p class="matchingClass">
this should be in a summary<br>this would be within the expandable details tag
</p>
```

And it should end up like...

```
<p class="matchingClass"><details><summary>
this should be in a summary</summary><br>this would be within the expandable details tag
</details></p>
```

I thought I had this working with the following code....

```
$(".matchingClass").each(function() {
     $(this).prepend("<details><summary>");
     $(this).find("br").first().before().prepend("</summary>");
     $(this).append("</details>");  
});
```

BUT i now realise that jquery/javascript always inserts closing tags automatically.  So as soon as the first of the 3 commands I apply runs the html doesn't end up how I expected it.

Can someone please assist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/RJktH/

```
$('.matchingClass').each(function () {
    var t = $(this).html();
    $(this).html('<summary>' + t.replace('<br>', '</summary>'));
});

$('.matchingClass').wrapInner('<details/>');
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this :

```
$('.matchingClass').each(function(){
    $(this).contents().first().wrap('<summary>');
    $(this).contents().wrapAll('<details>');
});
```

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/kkDFe/

Comment: Should be `details` (plural) not `detail`

Comment: Also, this will not work as required if there are any other markup before the first `<br/>`...

Comment: That's is true, but from the original code of the OP, he doesnt have "different markup", so a static solution can work for him.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution might be simple string parsing:

```
$('.matchingClass').each(function() {
    var html = $(this).html();
    var parts = html.split('<br>');
    var firstPart = parts.splice(0,1); // support multiple <br> elements
    html = '<details><summary>' + firstPart + '</summary><br>' + parts.join('<br>') + '</details>';
    $(this).html(html);
});
```

Of course, the *ideal* solution would be to change the server-side code to generate the markup you want without having to mess with it using javascript.

Comment: Thanks Jason.  Great demo as well... gvee's a little more minimal but same idea.  Thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

Not pretty by any means, but it works:

```
var $p = $('.matchingClass')
var $details = $('<details />')

$p.contents().filter(function() {
    return this.nodeType == 3; // textNode
}).each(function(i, node) {
    i == 0 ? 
        $('<summary />', { text: node.nodeValue }).appendTo($details) :
        $details.append(node.nodeValue)
});

$p.empty().append($details);
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/GHh2M/1/)