# jQuery: Target line after last <br>, add <span> to style it

Tags: jquery

Here's the code I have currently

```
<div class="desc-wrapper">Dr <br>
Crendetials<br>
Lecturer</div>
```

First I need to look for the text after the last `<br>` then I need to add `<span></span>` between `Lecturer` so I can style it via CSS.

How do I achieve this in jQuery?

Comment: I'm not really sure to understand what you are trying to achieve, but from what i understand i suggest you to have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18831079/adding-wrapping-tags-to-text-before-and-after-a-specific-tag-with-jquery) . hope it helps

Comment: Thanks @FranckNgako this looks neat. I'm going to try something out using the link you provided

Comment: Thanks @FranckNgako I am currently using the solution here. https://stackoverflow.com/posts/18831171/revisions Awesome!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's just one of many ways to do this:

```
$( $('div.desc-wrapper').children('br').last().get(0).nextSibling ).wrap('<span />');
```

The `$('div.desc-wrapper').children('br').last()` part gets the last `<br>`. The `.get(0)` gets us the native JavaScript object instead of the jQuery object which then allows us to use `.nextSibling` to get the actual text after the `<br>`. We wrap that all up in a jQuery object so we can use jQuery again to wrap that text in a span with `.wrap('<span />')`

Example:

```js
$($('div.desc-wrapper').children('br').last().get(0).nextSibling).wrap('<span />');
```

```css
span {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="desc-wrapper">Dr <br> Crendetials
  <br> Lecturer
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution. I have one problem. I don't know how to place that code within my JS file. In my JS file, all jQuery functions sit in this function `jQuery(function($){   });` - when I place your code within this function, it doesn't seem to work